A smart way to transform a list of dataframes
I wonder if there's a built-in function or concrete way to transform a list of dataframes, say if a list l1 contains df1 and df2,
l1 = list(df1, df2).

Now I want df1 and df2 respectively, what I could come up is:
df1 <- purrr::chuck(l1, "df1").
df2 <- purrr::chuck(l1, "df2").

etc. But this will become a headache in case of a larger list.

Yes, there is: list2env(l1, envir = .GlobalEnv)

"Now I want df1 and df2 respectively," I do not understand. list2env()?
